# Передача массива из C# в C++ на заполнение

Tags: c#, массивы, c++

Добрый день.
Готовый продукт состоит из библиотеки dll (на C#) и самой программы (на C#). Необходимо увеличить быстродействие программы. Решено реализовать dll на C++. Исходного кода к программе полностью не имеется (подсмотрел с помощью рефлектора), только от dll. Столкнулся с проблемой заполнения массива на c++. Обратно возвращаемый массив через пойнтер без данных. С простым числом типа int проблем нет.
По идеи в программе подключение к dll выглядит следующем образом:

```
[DllImport ("core.dll")]
private static extern int getUsersList(uint country, out UsersData[] usersList);
```

Ответ функции - результат выполнения. Данные программа получает через аргумент.
Число программе возвращаю на C++ через функцию:

```
EXPORT_API int getNOfUser(uint country, int* nOfUser);
```

Получаю количество элементов. После чего на C# формируется массив:

```
UsersData[] result = new UsersData[nOfUser];
```

Далее в принципе и сам вопрос. Как правильно получить массив, заполнить его на C++ и вернуть в понятной форме программе на C#. Может имеете опыт работы в этом направлении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил подключив к C++ проекту /clr, теперь все работает :)